# Different team ID issue with code sign in Mac 10.15.1

Tags: postgresql, macos

I am using Mac 10.15.1.

I have installed PostgreSQL database which is signed by its certificate. User can extend the postgresql database by writing the extension so I have written the extension and created ".so" file which is signed by my certificates. I have used below command to sign the library file.

```
codesign --verbose --verify --deep -f -s '<My_Apple_ID>' --options runtime My_library.so
```

After loading this new library with installed postgresql database, it gives error of "different Team IDs" as below. This is because installed postgresql is signed with team ID XXX and  My_library.so is signed with team ID YYY.

> code signature in (My_library.so) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs

As in my Certificate Team ID is different and installed product have their own team ID.

So how can we resolve this issue?

Comment: I met the same error. Anyone? Please help.